# SaveAll cakephp 2x

Tags: cakephp

Na minha tabela `Escola` tenho uma outra tabela associada chamada `EscolaPercentual`.
E tenho um formulário que há dados das 2 tabelas, na hora de salvar na minha action eu dou um `SaveAll` no Modelo Escola, que tem `$hasMany` para o modeno `EscolaPercentual`, sendo assim, ele salva o que é de `Escola` em `Escola` e o que é de `EscolaPercentual` no mesmo.
O problema é que quando vou editar, se eu não redigitar todos os dados que são números decimais sobre `EscolaPercentual`, o banco de dados não aceita e fica tudo 999,99.
No modelo Escola percentual, debuguei usando `beforeSave` para ver como que os dados estavam indo, e descobri que `20.00` como estava sendo apresentado no meu formulário, mas quando debuguei vi que `20.00`, acabou virando `2000` e o banco de dados o transformou em `999,99` já que configurei a coluna para double.

Comment: O que tem em `EscolaPercentual` ? `999,99` seria o valor padrão caso nenhum seja informado? parece que tem alguma função desviando o seu código principal.

Comment: Sim, o problema é que o behavior que tratava isso não funciona com saveAll, então eu tratei os valores com beforeValidate, usando str_replace nos pontos para virgula.

Comment: Coloca esse código do str_replace

Comment: `public function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
        
        $this->data[$this->alias]['percentual'] = str_replace('.', ',', $this->data[$this->alias]['percentual']);
        return true;
        
    }`

Comment: No banco o separador para centavos é o ponto, você precisa fazer o inverso, trocar toque for virgula por ponto.